# Passing parameters between stacks / screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am struggeling with passing parameters between stacks / screens.

I have the following app container with several stacks:

```js
export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    Auth: AuthStack,
    Tab: TabStack,
    Menu: MenuStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
));
```

In the Auth Stack I have the Login Screen. After login I would like to pass the `userName` to the other stacks, e.g. in order to establish a web socket connection to my XMPP server.

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate('Tab', { userName: loginData.username })
```

Unfortunately, I don't have any idea how to access the `userName` parameter. I will always get undefined when calling `navigation.getParam('userName')` (I can confirm that `loginData.username` is not undefined).

Is it correct that parameters are not passed between stacks?

If yes then I know at least the reason for this behavior. But how can I pass the `userName` then (I read that `AsyncStorage` is a kind of an anti-pattern for these kind of information and setting up Redux for this case seems a bit over-engineered) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Navigation - How to pass data across different screens in TabNavigator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50412762/react-navigation-how-to-pass-data-across-different-screens-in-tabnavigator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix my issue by navigating to a concrete route instead of the stack name.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Map', { userName: loginData.username });
```

So Map route is part of the TabStack

Answer (score 0):

In the route you've gone to, you can access your parameters like this:

`this.props.navigation.state.params.userName`

This is located under "Summary" at the bottom of the [documentation page](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html). It's always worth checking if params is not null, since if there's no params `this.props.navigation.state.params` returns `null`.

```
if(this.props.navigation.state.params && this.props.navigation.state.params.userName) {
  //do something
}
```

This was the original way of getting route params before the `navigate.getParam()` function was introduced in `2.X`

Comment: Thanks ... I get 
```
TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.state.params.userName')
```

Comment: As mentioned above I need this parameter to establish a connection to my xmpp server. So I believe I need the parameter while creating the app container so that I can handle incoming xmpp messages for several screens.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you checkout this package:
https://github.com/vonovak/react-navigation-props-mapper
Simplifies this flow a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it NOT possible to pass parameters to a "**stack**". It seems that parameters can only be passed to a "**screen.**"

Passing parameters to a nested screen (a "**screen**", which is part of a "**stack**") has a different approach than passing parameters to a "**screen**", which is defined as a "**tab**".

```js
// example of a stack definition 
const Stack_1 = () => {
    const MyStack = createStackNavigator();
    return (
        <MyStack.Navigator>
            <MyStack.Screen name="Screen_1_in_Stack_1" component={Screen_1_in_Stack_1} />
        </MyStack.Navigator>
    );
};

// example for passing parameters to a screen, which is part of a stack: 
navigation.navigate('Stack_1', {
  screen: 'Screen_1_in_Stack_1',
  params: { userID: '123' },
});
```